# .gitignore_global ignored wrong dir and won't allow it to be tracked after removal

Tags: macos, git, laravel, gitignore, git-add

I accidentally added Laravel's `app/storage` dir to .gitignore_global. This caused problems of course, so I removed it from `.gitignore_global`.

Now no matter what I can't get any project to track `app/storage` or any of its subdirectories.

I've checked all `.gitignore` files for my projects and none mention "storage".

I tried running `git add storage -f` but this caused all `.gitignore` files in all the subdirectories to be ignored, which is not what I want since some files should not be added. If I just run `git add storage`, I get the error

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files: app/storage
```

What's going on here?

(For information, I'm running on Mac OS 10.9.)

Comment: *[...] this caused all .gitignore files in all the sub-directories to be ignored [...]* Don't you mean "added" rather than "ignored", here?

Comment: No, I mean ignored...as it git ignores what is contained in the .gitignore files in all sub-dirs. For instance, if one .gitignore file contains *.json as an ignore pattern, then the *.json files are still included in the tracking for the next commit despite what that .gitignore files says to do.

Comment: try `git check-ignore -v` for some file in there. it doesn't even have to exist.

Comment: @jthill that elucidated the .gitignore file in my user root dir that was causing the problem. You're my hero on this post! Please put this in the form of an answer so I can accept. :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git check-ignore -v` for some file in there, it doesn't even have to exist. That's always been very effective for me.